# Why does the following python code using max() work one way but not another?

Tags: python

I'm doing the exercism.io python test cases, so I'm a newbie at this language.
Is there an issue with passing a function that results in an integer to the max() function?

Python 3

This code does not work:
The error message is TypeError: 'int' object is not callable,
which is the error message that you get if there are not exactly two parameters to the max function.
Note: The code fails whether I have the (int) included or excluded in the max function.

The calculate_single function returns the product of list of integers.

**digits is a list of numeric lists.**

```
    ...
    largest = 0
    for digitlist in digits:
        largest = max((int)(calculate_single(digitlist)),largest)
    return largest

def calculate_single (digitlist):  
    current = 1  
    for digit in digitlist:  
        current *= (int)(digit)  
    return current
```

This code does work. I just want to know why the first one didn't work.

```
    ...
    largest = 0
    for digitlist in digits:
        largest = calculate_single(digitlist,largest)
    return largest

def calculate_single (digitlist,largest):
    current = 1
    for digit in digitlist:
        current *= (int)(digit)
    return max(current,largest)
```

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What is it doing then?  Is not `(int)` the same as `int` and thus `(int)(x)` equivalent to `int(x)`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist it does exactly the same as `int(digit)` in spite of the awkward syntax.

Comment: Please post the full error trace.

Comment: Somewhere in your first code, I suspect you used `int` as a variable name, so it no longer references the builtin type.

Comment: "... which is the error message that you get if there are not exactly two parameters to the max function." The error that you would actually get from calling `max` with a single integer argument is "TypeError: 'int' object is not *iterable*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @ShaneStewart I don't see anything abnormal here, I think you've to share you complete piece of code then only we can suggest the reason for getting this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried two versions of your code and seemed that both were just fine.
version 1:

```
def calculate_single(digitlist, largest):
    current = 1
    for digit in digitlist:
    current *= (int)(digit)
    return max(current, largest)

def calculate(digits):
    largest = 0
    for digitlist in digits:
        #print (largest)
        largest = calculate_single(digitlist, largest)
        #print (largest)
    return largest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [[2, 5, 7, 4.2, 3], [3.6, 6, 4, 2, 1], [5, 5, 5, 10,10]]
    big = calculate(lst)
    print(big)
```

version 2:

```
def calculate_single(digitlist):
    current = 1
    for digit in digitlist:
        current *= (int)(digit)
    return current

def calculate(digits):
    largest = 0
    for digitlist in digits:
        #print (largest)
        largest = max((calculate_single(digitlist)), largest)
        #print (largest)
    return largest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = [[2, 5, 7, 4.2, 3], [3.6, 6, 4, 2, 1], [5, 5, 5, 10,10]]
    #lst = [2, 3, 5, 8]
    big = calculate(lst)
    print(big)
```

I think the main thing is that digitlist is a list of numbers and digits is a list of lists. So a list should be passed on to calculate_single() and a list of lists should be passed on to calculate(). If a list is passed on to calculate() it will raise TypeError. In both versions max() seemed good no matter with/out int()

Answer (score -2):

Casting to `int` in python is done by: [int( )](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) not `(int)`.

Comment: `(int)` is the same as `int`, and therefore `(int)(x)` is the same as `int(x)`

Comment: Just tested it `(int)('2')` works perfectly fine and also `((((((int))))))('2')`

Comment: Never seem casting using (int). Where in the docs is this behaviour stated? Is it pythonic? I'm amazed this simple idiom flow under my radar for so long.

Comment: @f.rodrigues `(int)` itself is not a cast.  There's nothing special about it; it's just adding redundant parentheses.  Read what I and Bhargav Rao wrote.

Comment: Parentheses just dictate the order in which expressions are evaluated or for generator expressions @f.rodrigues. They do not serve any casting purpose and can be added redundantly everywhere. They are crucial for dictating operator precedence, but unlike C, in which you can cast with (int)value, in Python, the important part is the int call method, which still occurs with (int)(value), since (int)(value) tells the interpreter to do int(value) first, which is a fully redundant use of parentheses.